# Gaussian function python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the Gaussian function using matplotlib.
This is my code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import math

    def gaussian(x, alpha, r):
          return 1./(math.sqrt(alpha**math.pi))*np.exp(-alpha*np.power((x - r), 2.))

    x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
    plt.plot(gaussian(x, 1, 0))

    plt.show()
```

Why the range is from 0 to 100 instead of being between -3 and 3?[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **plot(y)**: plot y using x as index array 0..N-1
- **plot(x, y)**: plot x and y using default line style and color

Change `plt.plot(gaussian(x, 1, 0))` to `plt.plot(x, gaussian(x, 1, 0))`

Output:

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!